# libgdx toJson() to update integer field on Parse.com via REST API

Tags: java, json, parse-platform, libgdx

When I use toJson() method of libgdx, I get a json string that does not include integer fields that hold a zero value.

It seems this behavior is by design (though I haven't found documentation about it). However I need also zero fields to be included in the json string, because I need that string to update a Parse.com row that includes integer fields, and some of those must be set to zero.

I do I work around that libgdx limitation?

Comment: This problem exist also for the Parse PHP SDK for numeric fields with value = 0 and boolean fields with value = false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the LibGDX Json class does not write default values for fields (this extends beyond just number values) because it doesn't need them to deserialize. This can be problematic when using other frameworks to deserialize, as you have found.

You can disable this behavior and write all fields by calling `json.setUsePrototypes(false)` before you call `json.toJson()`.